# Android - how access to path

Tags: android, functional-programming

i need to get image from path in Android .

Access to android path code is :

```
File myhtml =new File("/Phone/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20140509-WA0002.jpg");
```

Android path check :

```
if(myhtml.exists())
 {
  System.out.println("true");
 }
else
 {
  System.out.println("false");
 }
```

When i checking if this file exists it returns "false" .
I tried to find how to write file path of android correctly - but i dont find solution for it .

Comment: You should read following article: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: i read it , it doesnt help me . i try any thing  that was there and it doesnt work. but thank you .

Answer (score 0):

So, if you read the link provided in the comments, you know that there are two types of data storage, internal and external.  The way you're referencing the data in your example refers to internal data.  That's why it doesn't exist.

This is how you reference external storage:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
           "/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20140509-WA0002.jpg"));
```

You will also need to add this to your manifest eventually:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: File file = New File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera/")
This get the directory - but when i try to access to specific file it doesnt allow me it writes that the file dont exists .